# Hour in input date Blazor

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, blazor

I'm tried to set a hour in input date in blazor, but i don't know if it is possible.

My code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="Validade" class="p-3">Validade</label>
    <InputDate @bind-Value:format="dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss" @bind-Value="@InfracaoDto.Validade" />
    <ValidationMessage For="@(()=>InfracaoDto.Validade)" />
</div>
```

Result:

[image]

Is there any way of the input get hour, minute and second?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
  <InputDate @bind-Value:format="dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss" @bind-Value="@InfracaoDto.Validade" />
```

to

```
<InputDate Type="InputDateType.DateTimeLocal" @bind-Value:format="dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss" @bind-Value="@InfracaoDto.Validade"/>
```

Comment: Nice, works here, thanks.